# ASP.NET ProfileBase.Create behavior when supplied with an existing username

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

When supplied with a username that already exists, does ProfileBase.Create return the ProfileBase associated with the existing user (and if the username does not exisit, creates a new user and returns the new user)?

Apologies for the trivial question, but MSDN documentation really is of little help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code for `ProfileBase.Create()`:

```
public static ProfileBase Create(string username, bool isAuthenticated)
{
    if (!ProfileManager.Enabled)
    {
        throw new ProviderException(SR.GetString("Profile_not_enabled"));
    }
    InitializeStatic();
    if (s_SingletonInstance != null)
    {
        return s_SingletonInstance;
    }
    if (s_Properties.Count == 0)
    {
        lock (s_InitializeLock)
        {
            if (s_SingletonInstance == null)
            {
                s_SingletonInstance = new DefaultProfile();
            }
            return s_SingletonInstance;
        }
    }
    HttpRuntime.CheckAspNetHostingPermission(AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low, "Feature_not_supported_at_this_level");
    return CreateMyInstance(username, isAuthenticated);
}


private static ProfileBase CreateMyInstance(string username, bool isAuthenticated)
{
    Type profileType;
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        profileType = BuildManager.GetProfileType();
    }
    else
    {
        profileType = InheritsFromType;
    }
    ProfileBase base2 = (ProfileBase) Activator.CreateInstance(profileType);
    base2.Initialize(username, isAuthenticated);
    return base2;
}
```

Looks like it always returns a new instance of ProfileBase.

Comment: Thanks - this is very useful. What were the steps you went through to get this code?

Answer (score 1):

As I thought, the *Create* method actually retrieves the profile. Who designs these APIs?!

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126719/asp-net-sql-profile-provider-does-the-profilebase-create-method-hit-db).

Comment: I completely agree that while the Membership & Roles providers are great, the Profile part has been poorly designed.