# How to load the profile of a newly-logged-in user before the redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, visual-web-developer, asp.net-profiles

I started an ASP.NET MVC 2 project and I am building off of the code that was generated automatically.

The problem that I am experiencing is that after a user is logged in, it appears that the profile of the newly-logged-in user is not loaded into the `HttpContext`, so I get a `ProviderException` with the message "This property cannot be set for anonymous users" when attempting to set a property value in the current user's profile.

For the POST-only LogOn action, Visual Web Developer 2010 Express basically generated:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        //...
```

where `FormsService` is a property of the controller of type `FormsAuthenticationService` (also generated):

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

After the `FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)` line I was assuming that information for the newly-logged-in account would be immediately available to the controller, but this does not appear to be the case. If, for example, I add `profile.SetPropertyValue("MyProfileProperty", "test")` below the call to FormsService#SignIn, then I get the `ProviderException` "This property cannot be set for anonymous users".

How do I load the newly-logged-in user's profile into the `HttpContext` so that I can set a property value in his or her profile before the next request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naming of the function is counter intuitive, but ProfileBase.Create(username) will load the existing profile for an existing user or create a new profile if none exists.

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
```

This will not load the profile into `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Profile` but at least you can access or alter the user profile.

Comment: No, you're wrong to assume that, it will load an existing profile. Try it out.

Comment: "It took some time until I realized that calling ProfileBase.Create() with a username as argument performs a lookup against TableStorage and actually retrieves the data associated with that username. As far as I'm concerned, calling this method Create() is misleading, I would expect Load() or Get()." see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126719/asp-net-sql-profile-provider-does-the-profilebase-create-method-hit-db

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you Steven! (To anyone who might read this seeking a similar solution, be sure to call [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.save.aspx) on the profile object if you make changes.)

Answer (score 1):

The "raw" Forms authentication built into the MVC template does not automatically load the profile.  All it does is validate the user against the Membership tables and set the login cookie.  If you want profile data persisted in Session state on login, you'll have to do that explicitly:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                LoadProfile(model.UserName);
            }
     }

     private void LoadProfile(string UserName)
     {
          MyModelContext ctx = new MyModelContext(); //EF or LINQ2SQL context
          var user = ctx.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
          Session.Add("CurrentUser", user);
     }
```

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood the original question.  You have to create and save a profile of type `ProfileCommon` for anonymous users.  See this post:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1150958/2619264.aspx

Comment: I'm assuming the profile then is loaded into Session when the "next" page is loaded after logging in.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Nick: In this implementation, the profile is loaded into session immediately upon validation, before the redirect.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how does this load the profile (`ControllerContext.HttpContext.Profile`) of the newly-logged-in user?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm assuming that the OP is connecting to the Membership tables in a SQL database.  The sample code above demonstrates the idea of using an Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL context to connect to that database and load the profile.  If the profile is being stored somewhere else, a different method would be used to load it.